# Flutter. При запуске приложения, как лучше запросить асинхронные данные ? [Best Practices]

Tags: api, flutter, dart, contentprovider

Сейчас работаю над приложением и при запуске необходимо получить по API userId, а затем подписаться на сокеты:

```html
final userId = await fetchUser();
subscribeSocket(userId)
```

Трудность в том, что до инициализации провайдера, т.е. в **main** методе нельзя вызывать, т.к. не смогу сохранить информацию о user. Если в **FutureBuilder**, то получу повторный вызов подписки несколько раз (видимо из-за рендера). Как вариант **intialState**, но у меня сомнения в правильности.

Answer (score 0):

initState у State нормальный вариант, но лучше переходить на [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно вызывать ф-ию при запуске - `initState()` шикарный вариант. Опять же, как уже было в ответе выше - `bloc`, будет лучшим решением (если он нужен). Как говорил дядюшка Боб,

> не стоит использовать чистую архитектуру там, где она не нужна.